# get sympy result as trig function rather than complex log

Tags: python, sympy, trigonometry

I'm doing some manipulation of trig equations and would like the results back in trig form.

What I'm doing is this:

```
from sympy import *
B,D,a=symbols(r'B,D,alpha',real=True,positive=True)
eq1=Eq(D,B*((sin(a)*sin(a))/(sin(a+a))))
solve(eq1,a)
```

I expect the result to be `atan(2*D/B)` but I'm getting:

```
[-I*log(-sqrt((B + 2*I*D)/(B - 2*I*D))), -I*log((B + 2*I*D)/(B - 2*I*D))/2]
```

I know sympy is expanding the trig functions into exponential form, but I can't seem to convince it to convert the results back.

I've tried:

```
[n.rewrite(atan) for n in solve(eq1,a)]
```

but I get the same result back...

Comment: have you tried using simplify() or trigsimp()   https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.0/modules/simplify.html#trigsimp

Comment: I did try those on the result, without luck.  Of course I didn't try them /before/ the solve, which does resove the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simplify **before** solving, the result looks better.

```
>>> solve(eq1.simplify(), a)
[atan(2*D/B)]
```

Also, the more mathematically rigorous `solveset` (a modern alternative to `solve`) returns a more mathematically correct answer without the need for simplification:

```
>>> solveset(eq1, a)
ConditionSet(alpha, Eq(tan(alpha)/2 - D/B, 0), Reals)
```

The point being that there are infinitely many solutions, so they cannot be given as a list: so, solveset presents them as the set of all alpha such that `tan(alpha)` is `2*D/B`.

Comment: In this case, I'm using it for engineering purposes so the one solution is enough... ;-)  Thanks.  Tried every way I could think of to fix the output, didn't think to tweak the input.